# How configure Distribute Virtual Router(DVR) on Neutron with JUJU?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I installed Ubuntu Openstack using Autopilot. I try configure DVR with neutron-api charm activating dvr.

When I run the command "neutron agent-list" It's possible to see that the Open Vswitch Agents on the computes nodes have been created  but the iniatial L3 agent and the other neutron services on the network node are died.

How can I debug this error? I'm checking /var/log/neutron but the logs not show anything.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Checking the issue. I discover that when I make a change on neutron-gateway charm the all neutron components at network node fail.

The right logs are stored at /var/log/upstar. Cheking the log neutron-openvswitch-agent.log I saw the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/neutron-openvswitch-agent", line 6, in 
    from neutron.cmd.eventlet.plugins.ovs_neutron_agent import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/cmd/eventlet/plugins/ovs_neutron_agent.py", line 16, in 
    import neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.main as agent_main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/openvswitch/agent/main.py", line 24, in 
    from neutron.common import config as common_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/common/config.py", line 28, in 
    from oslo_service import wsgi
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_service/wsgi.py", line 29, in 
    from paste import deploy
ImportError: cannot import name deploy

The solution was uninstall and install again paste and paste.deploy:
  $ pip uninstall paste
  $ pip install paste
  $ pip uninstall pastedeploy
  $ pip install pastedeploy